# calculating total time in sql

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there anyway that I can add these two queries together? Actually I want the overall time with athlete table name attributes.

I have tried Nested Select statement but that's not working as well

These are my tables:

**Athlete**

```
Name          Null     Type         
------------- -------- ------------ 
ATHLETE_NO    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
FIRST_NAME    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
LAST_NAME     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
DOB           NOT NULL DATE         
ADDRESS_LINE1          CHAR(25)     
POSTCODE               CHAR(25)     
COUNTRY                CHAR(25)     
EMAIL                  VARCHAR2(20) 
GENDER                 VARCHAR2(10)
```

**TRIATHLETE_TP**

```
Name             Null     Type         
---------------- -------- ------------ 
TRANSITION_TIME1          VARCHAR2(8)  
TRANSITION_TIME2          VARCHAR2(8)  
CYCLE_TIME                VARCHAR2(8)  
RUN_TIME                  VARCHAR2(8)  
SWIM_TIME                 VARCHAR2(8)  
RANKING                   NUMBER(38)   
ATHLETE_NO       NOT NULL NUMBER(38)   
RACE_NAME        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20) 
RACE_DATE        NOT NULL DATE
```

**Queries:**

```
with x AS (
  select Transition_Time1,
         Transition_Time2,
         Cycle_Time,
         Swim_Time,
         Run_Time,

         substr(Transition_Time1,1,2) * 3600 +
         substr(Transition_Time1,4,2) * 60   +
         substr(Transition_Time1,7,2)            as t1_secs,
         substr(Transition_Time2,1,2) * 3600 +
         substr(Transition_Time2,4,2) * 60   +
         substr(Transition_Time2,7,2)            as t2_secs,
         substr(Cycle_Time,1,2) * 3600 +
         substr(Cycle_Time,4,2) * 60   +
         substr(Cycle_Time,7,2)            as C_secs,
         substr(Swim_Time,1,2) * 3600 +
         substr(Swim_Time,4,2) * 60   +
         substr(Swim_Time,7,2)            as S_secs,
         substr(Run_Time,1,2) * 3600 +
         substr(Run_Time,4,2) * 60   +
         substr(Run_Time,7,2)            as R_secs

  from TRIATHLETE_TP
  ),
y as (
  select Transition_Time1,Transition_Time2,Cycle_Time,Swim_Time,Run_Time,
         numtodsinterval(t1_secs + t2_secs + C_secs + S_secs + R_secs,'second') time_intvl
from x
  )
select Transition_Time1 , Transition_Time2 ,Cycle_Time,Swim_Time,Run_Time,
       extract(day from time_intvl) * 24 +
       extract(hour from time_intvl) ||':' ||
       extract(minute from time_intvl) ||':' ||
       extract(second from time_intvl) Overall_Time
from y
```

OR

```
select m.FIRST_NAME,m.LAST_NAME,t.Transition_Time1 , t.Transition_Time2 ,t.Cycle_Time,t.Swim_Time,t.Run_Time
from ATHLETE m JOIN TRIATHLETE_TP t
ON (m.ATHLETE_NO = t.ATHLETE_NO)
```

Comment: Your query is not MyQL.  Please tag with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Perhaps it is (MS) SQL-Server, given the CTE

Comment: I assume you're really using Oracle.  Why are you storing the times as strings rather than as intervals?  It would be much easier to sum the intervals than to parse the strings to get the various components, convert those to intervals, add them, and then parse the results.